# How do use the tweet_mode='extended' in Twitter Api when streaming tweets?

Tags: python, api, twitter, stream, tweepy

```
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)   
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='to:3NASA', tweet_mode='extended').items(limit)
```

I always get an error

File "stream.py", line 41, in 
    tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='to:3NASA', tweet_mode='extended').items(limit)
AttributeError: module 'api' has no attribute 'search'

Answer (score 2):

The streaming API does not have the option to add that parameter. This is [documented on Twitter's developer site](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/tweet-updates).

> The Streaming API does not provide the same ability to provide query
>   parameters to configure request options. Therefore, the Streaming API
>   renders all Tweets in compatibility mode at this time.
>
> Tweets rendered in compatibility mode for the streaming APIs, unlike
>   for the REST APIs, will include the extended_tweet field for any
>   extended tweet. This is necessary to avoid breaking existing clients
>   by sending text that is longer than they expect in the existing text
>   field, and also to provide the entirety of the data in a single
>   stream. If there is an extended_tweet field, it will also include the
>   ranges described above.
>
> Streaming API consumers should update their code to first check for
>   the presence of the extended_tweet dictionary, and use that in
>   preference to the truncated data as is applicable for their use case.
>   When extended_tweet is not present, they must fall back to using the
>   existing fields.

You'll receive the extended format Tweets anyway inside the `extended_tweet` payload.